# Use getimagesize in conditional statement php

Tags: php, security, upload, getimagesize

I want to assure that an uploaded image has dimensions. I run a test that should disallow the upload if the image dimensions are greater than `50`. Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_FILES['fupload'])) {

    $filename = strtolower(($_FILES['fupload']['name']));
    $ext = substr($filename, -4);
    $filename = explode('.',$filename);
    $filename = $filename[0];
    $filename = str_shuffle($filename);

    $filename = $filename.$ext; 

    $source = $_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name'];   
    $target =  $path_to_image_directory.$filename;

    $size = getimagesize($filename);

    if( $size[0] > 20 || $size[1] > 20 ) {
        echo 'Too Large!';

    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($source, $target);

        createThumbnail($filename);

        $title= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['title']);
        $keyword1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['keyword1']);
        $keyword2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['keyword2']);
        $keyword3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['keyword3']);

        $Q = "INSERT INTO images (name, title, keyword1,keyword2,      keyword3)VALUES('$filename', '$title', '$keyword1','$keyword2','$keyword3')";

        if(!mysqli_query($connection, $Q)) {
            die("error inserting into pres name".mysqli_error($connection));
        }   
    }
}
```

I would expect the message "Too Large!" when I try to upload a large image, but I don't. The image uploads no matter how large it is. My end goal is to switch the greater than sign to the less than sign to assure that the file has actual dimensions.

I got this conditional statement from stackoverflow:

```
if($size[0] > 20 || $size[1] > 20) {
    echo 'Too Large!';
}
```

It seems like it should prevent the upload, but it doesn't. Can anyone please help me understand?

Comment: You need to feed `getimagesize` with the current filepath, which is `$_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name']` at the time of calling the function.

Comment: Also you should probably check if `$size` is (strictly) equal to `false`, otherwise I could upload any non-image file.

Comment: what do you get when you print_R($size)?

Comment: I did what Charlotte Dunois suggested and it worked as expected. I also added the check if $size is (strictly) equal to false. I tested in on a php file with the extension changed to jpg and the upload failed as I wanted. Thanks for the good advise.

Answer (score 0):

you may use

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($_FILES["fupload"]["tmp_name"]);

if(($width>20)||($height>20)){
                $error = "Image Dimemsions Exceed Allowed Dimensions";
                return $error;
            }
```

hope it helps ;)